# Prevent site configuration info from showing up on Google

Tags: html, css, seo

I have a site that's running WordPress.

The main page has an embedded Flash player and an imbedded iframe, and for some reason, all the configuration info from the Flash player is showing up on Google for my site, and nothing else.

How can I have the main site information show up on Google, without having that Flash player config info show up?

And can I customize what shows up at all?

If there's some way to tag the info I don't want to show up, or tag the info I want to show up, I can probably do most ofthe edits myself, I just don't know where to start...

EDIT: I tried most of the suggestions below, and I didn't get anywhere...
Any other ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Google, or other crawler to access certain parts of your website you should use a robots.txt file. Inside you specify which parts are accessible and which aren't, when the crawlers get to your website will always look for this file for instructions.

You can check some documentation on how to do it [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449) and [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/robots.shtml)

Comment: I want the site and pages accessible and indexed, I just want some parts of the page(s) blocked...

Comment: That I'm not sure is possible, you can restrict whole pages or directories, but if a crawler accesses a page I think it read the whole page.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find put, there should be a way to restrict some of a page, especially a configuration file. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Mmm, are you trying to block a part of a page or a configuration file??

Comment: What shows up in Google, is a different line for every page of your website, so if you want to block everything that is like requests.jewishmusicstream.com/web/playlist.php?, it can be done with the robots file

Answer (score 1):

In order to influence what text is used on the google search result try putting this within your head tags

```
<meta name="description" content="WHATEVER YOU WANT DISPLAYED ON GOOGLE">
```

Source: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Some more information from google on controling parts of a page. Apparently there are google off/google on tags.

http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/08/23/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Google "claims" it does if the site doesn't have better content to display. Using flash as the main provider of content on a webpage makes it difficult for google to parse.

Comment: Just double checked, and I already have a description meta tag there, guess it didn't do anything...

Comment: Yeah, just saw that. Granted, I remember last time I was working on tweaking my Google search results it would take some time to see changes. I'd assume this to be limited to how often google crawls a site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Google to index only part of your pages, you can't follow normal SEO routines. You should provide a mechanism to understand whether the current client (requester) is a robot or not. If yes, then don't render that part. This is the only way. Otherwise, a robot either gets the whole rendered content, or doesn't have access based on robots.txt file (Robot Exclusion Protocol).

Another way (which is not really smart, and can't be guaranteed to work) is to dynamically inject your content into the page via JavaScript. Because AMAIK, robots don't run JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As search spiders won't render javascript generated markup (JS is not run as it is client-side in the browser), a quick fix would be to don't output any of flash / markup initially in the HTML document and then use JS to add the flash stuff on load.

Note: as far as I'm aware, Google is currently testing a JS reading spider so this may not work long term.

Answer (score 1):

1. Google is returning this data because ***it simply can't find any content where it normally would***. Search engines require content - they're not advanced enough to process your multimedia to determine what it's all about.
2. [Google will IGNORE your meta description](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35264) if it doesn't feel that it reflects your page content (of which there is only iframes and JS)
3. Use [SWFObject to provide  alternate content](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#How_to_embed_Flash_Player_content_using_SWFObject_dynamic_publis) for users without flash (including search engines) - ensure it's not some dinky text like "download flash here" - but a **lengthy descriptive content** piece about your site or media that they would normally experience if they could experience.
4. Use `robots.txt` or `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">` for the iframe content to prevent it from being indexed.
5. For the **love of all things holy**, please look at reducing the number of JS files and    inline JS on your site (i'd recommend [WP-minify](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/) since it's so obvious that you love plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The theme uses a lot of JS, not much I can do about that, but I'll try that plugin - looks cool, and I never knew about it - thanks!
With alternate content, I am using a WP plugin to allow me to add the Flash player to the site - do I put the alternate content there?
And is it possible to block the Flash xml config file from being indexed?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could add the xml config file to your robots.txt to block it.

Comment: I added a nofollow tag in, and added it to the robots.txt file, we'll see if that works - thanks!

Comment: to be fair, that can happen depending on when/where your JS is being called in relation to your DOM elements. If you're game, W3TC is another option that will significantly clean-up/speed-up your site